# How to structure nested Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a situation where I think the only choice for me is to nest some Promises within each other. I have a Promise that needs to be performed and a method that does something until that Promise is complete. Something like this:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  // Do some stuff

});

doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone(promise);
```

However, within my Promise, I need to execute another method that returns another Promise:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  fetchValue(url)
    .then((value) => {

      // Do something here

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

});

doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone(promise);
```

But now, in the `fetchValue` method's `then` statement, I have another method I need to execute that, guess what, returns another Promise:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  fetchValue(url)
    .then((value) => {

      saveToCache(value)
        .then((success) => {

          console.log('success!!');
          resolve('success');

        });

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

});

doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone(promise);
```

So in the end, I have a Promise, within a Promise, within a Promise. Is there someway I can structure this better so that it is more straightforward? It seems like nesting them within each other is counter to Promise's intended chaining approach.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to code async calls backs with Promise -- why not just use callbacks instead?

Comment: Where do you call `resolve()`?

Comment: Where is the `got` method?

Comment: Sorry the `got` was a typo. I was referring to the `fetchValue` method.

Comment: @Soren Well, `doSomethingUntilPromiseIsDone` takes a Promise. `fetchValue` returns a Promise, and `savetoCache` returns a Promise. If Promises are what these methods are returning how would I use callbacks at all?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry I added it in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.then()`

```
let doStuff = (resolve, reject) => {/* resolve() or reject() */};
let promise = new Promise(doStuff);
doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone(
  promise 
  .then(value => fetchValue(url))
  .then(value => value.blob())
  .then(saveToCache)
)
.then(success => console.log("success!!"))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: If you are already using the arrow syntax, why are you still using `return`...?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Good point. Not sure if `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` is necessary?

Comment: I just added spaces before `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` since the formatting was wrong. I don't know what that is actually.

Comment: If we are code-golfing, `catch` could just be `.catch(console.error)` and the first `then` would be just `.then(fetchValue)`

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that this might not work for OP.

Comment: `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` is necessary. Also in your answer, would `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` stop as soon as `promise` is done or would it continue until all the `then`'s are done as well? I need `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` to do its thing until the `saveToCache` is complete.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does not work. The problem with this approach is that `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` needs to wait until the entire Promise chain is complete. Not just the initial `promise` as shown in your example.

Comment: @JakeWilson Can you include the function body of `doSomethingUntilPromiseisDone` at Question?

Comment: It's the setStatusBarMessage method for the VSCode extension API. I have on idea what the inside of the method looks like. (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window)

Comment: _"I have on idea what the inside of the method looks like."_ What does the function return? _"I have confirmed that this does not work."_ What is issue with pattern at Answer? Can you describe "does not work"?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `generator` to flatten your nested promises ([Bluebird.couroutine](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) or [Generators](https://www.promisejs.org/generators))

```
//Bluebird.couroutine
const generator = Promise.coroutine(function*() {
  try {
     const value = yield fetchValue(url);
     const success = yield saveToCache(value);
     console.log('success:', success);
  } catch(e) {
     console.error(err);
  }    
}));

generator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each function will call the next one with the result of the method before.

```
var promises = [1,2,3].map((guid)=>{
    return (param)=> {
      console.log("param", param);
      var id = guid;
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        // resolve in a random amount of time
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(id);
        }, (Math.random() * 1.5 | 0) * 1000);
      });
    }
}).reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {
  return acc.then(function (res) {
    return curr(res[index-1]).then(function (result) {
      console.log("result", result);
      res.push(result);
      return res;
    });
  });
}, Promise.resolve([]));
promises.then(console.log);
```