# Passing a value from one request to another request in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help because I couldn't use a separate function to generate the token - it gives out a promise, not a value. I was told that a value can only be used inside a function.

For each request, I generate a new token in the first request and then pass that token into the second request.

I tried making a separate function to generate the token, but fetch returns a promise.

As a result, I made such a big function and it works.
Is there a way to make a separate function for the first request and pass the result to the second request?

The first token generation function is required frequently, while the second request is always different.

```
    fetch('/api/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'id': '5' }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {

    fetch('/api/reviews', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10 }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
          this.setState({ data: result.data });
      })

    })
```

Comment: These [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981040/using-a-fetch-inside-another-fetch-in-javascript) may help. I think you are missing `return` or something

Comment: OOoh boy. I highly suggest you try learning the async/await syntax, it's super helpful for long and complicated promise based code. This isn't to solve your code per-se, but it sure does make debugging and reading easier.

Comment: @Usama I think you're right, he probably needs to return the fetch call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function that return promise

```
async function getToken() {
   return await fetch('/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'id': '5' }),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            return Promise.resolve(result.token);
        }).catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        })
}


async function getReview() {
    const token = await getToken().then(token => {
        return token
    }).catch(error => {
        //handle error
    });
    fetch('/api/reviews', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10 }),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({ data: result.data });
        })

}
```

i did not test this code but you get the idea

i will test and update my answer asap

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). It will allow you to lift the lexical scope of the API response from inside the `.then` ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/) and into the parent function scope.

Your separate function which fetches the token will return a promise, but then the requesting function will wait for the promise to execute and resolve before continuing.

```js
async function fetchToken() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'id': '5' }),
  })
  return await response.json();
}

async function getReviews() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/reviews', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10 }),
  })
  const result = await response.json();
  this.setState({ data: result.data });
}
```

Additionally, if the token call does not need to be made every time the reviews call is made, then you can [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) the value, and use that memoized value.

```
const tokenMemo = useMemo(async () => await getToken(), []);

async function getReviews() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/reviews', {
  // ...
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenMemo,
  // ...
}
```