# Calling [promise's] resolve multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have this function which returns a promise as it's fetching asynchronously data. As you see there are watchers inside the code of that promise ($watchCollection) which keeps watching data and triggers the promise's resolve function for each change.

I can't test whether the then will triggers multiple times once for each resolve function call or not. Is this possible ?

```
this.getGridDataAndMetaData = function(viewId) {          

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        dataStore.fetchView(viewId)
            .then(function(viewEntity) {

                var grid_groupement = viewEntity.descriptor.state ? viewEntity.descriptor.state.grid_groupement : undefined;
                var dataStoreEntities = viewEntity.getEntityType().getEntities();
                var dataStoreProperties = viewEntity.getEntityType().getProperties();

                var gridDataAndMetaData;

                $rootScope.$watchCollection(function() {
                        return dataStoreEntities;
                    },
                    function(newCollection, oldCollection) {    

                        if (!angular.equals(newCollection, {}))
                            formatDataStoreEntities(angular.copy(newCollection), grid_groupement)
                            .then(function(data) {  


                                gridDataAndMetaData = data;                                            

                                if (lastNewProperties != undefined && !angular.equals(lastNewProperties, [])) {
                                    data.viewEntity = viewEntity;
                                    data.grid_groupement = grid_groupement;
                                    data.properties = lastNewProperties;   

                                    resolve(data);
                                }
                            });

                    });

                $rootScope.$watchCollection(function() {
                        return dataStoreProperties;
                    },
                    function(newProperties, oldProperties) {                                    
                        lastNewProperties = angular.copy(newProperties);                                    
                        if (gridDataAndMetaData != undefined && !angular.equals(gridDataAndMetaData.valuesIdsEntitiesTabFormat, {})) {                                                        
                            generateServiceTabs(newProperties, function() {
                                data.viewEntity = viewEntity;
                                data.grid_groupement = grid_groupement;
                                data.properties = lastNewProperties;

                                resolve(data);
                            });
                        }
                    });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('%c getGridDataAndMetaData :: dataStore.fetchView(viewId):: error : ' + JSON.stringify(error), 'background: red; color: white; display: block;');
                reject(error);
            });


    });

}
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I have replaced the promise with a callback , i can't test if it will run or not for each data update (= watcher execution). I prefer a callback than using one more library for the observable pattern

Comment: ES6 promises are not AngularJS promises. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. **Use $q service promises** to bring `.then` blocks into the AngularJS execution context.

Comment: **Don't use watchers inside `.then` blocks**. It will cause memory leaks. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: the returned viewEntity object (by the then()) contains a reference of data and meta data i'm using in my app , i need watchers to be up to date with data changes

Comment: A Promise (Angular or JavaScript) is only ever settled **once**. Once you've called `resolve` or `reject`, subsequent calls to either of them are completely ignored. You probably want an `Observable` instead, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-promise-vs-observable) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resolve` function that is the argument of `Promise` executor function is executed at most once. A `Promise` can only be fulfilled once. Note, that given `dataStore.fetchView(viewId)` returns a `Promise` the `Promise` constructor is not necessary.

Comment: thanks for quick answer , which pattern do you think can be suitable for this situation ?

Comment: You can use the existing `.then()` without `Promise` constructor. Note, have not tried angularjs. If the inquiry is specific to angularjs, see @T.J.Crowder Answer

Comment: @Bardelman See also [How to structure nested Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232165/how-to-structure-nested-promises/)

Comment: Do you think a callback for the main function instead the promise would work multiple times?

Comment: A callback for what?